# Why won't my divs overlap?

Tags: css, transform, overlap

I'm trying to get these divs to overlap and have the text be inside the triangle but the text can only be moved around outside the triangle.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CR47/GHWcZ/6/)

This is the HTML+CSS:

```
<div class="tri">
    <div class="test">
        This is test
    </div>
```

```
.tri {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid black;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    position:relative;
}

.test {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    zoom:1;
    margin-top:-80px;
    margin-left:-80px;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: like this? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHWcZ/8/)

Comment: @Mr.Alien - I forget nothing :-) JSFidlle from CR47 is different to the css posted here...

Comment: @dqf13g32g actually I deleted cuz I thought our solutions are similar but they weren't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `position: relative;` for the container element and than use `position: absolute;` for the child element, this way, your absolute positioned element won't flow out in the wild, and will be relative to the parent element, also it will be overlapped this way

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GHWcZ/9/)

---

Also it's a CSS triangle with borders and `height` and `width` set to `0` respectively, so you cannot expect an the child element to overlap the triangle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are trying to achive here.
If you want the text to be inside the black triangle, you could just edit out

```
display:inline-block;
```

Worked in JSFiddle, only tested in FireFox and Chrome though, might want to check more browsers.